# How to clean up a GCC Makefile

Tags: gcc, makefile

I just took over a GCC project containing a makefile that has *way* to many include folders and source files listed. I started removing one by one and verified by compiling, but wondered, is there some way of looking at the compiled output (map files for instance?) and compare that to the makefile to clean out unnecessary files?

I'm not saying this will make any difference to the finished project, but I like to quickly look at the Makefile to see what this project involves. Now it looks like it involves "everything"

Comment: The question is too broad. Can you at least share (partial) Makefile and highlight the items that you want removed. Since this is GCC project - can you share URL to source tree ?

Comment: It's, unfortunately, a closed source project. I guess I can make a mockup project though. I guess this is too broad, as I forgot to say it's a C-project? I am looking for a generic way of doing the job, so was hoping the lack of source wouldn't matter.